# What is the role of server in Push Notification for Android and IOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services, android-push-notification

I am a bit Confused in Push Notification concept,
I mean can I send notification to all registered users from firebase console after my application is live.
If yes then What is the role of server (like MS Azure or AWS etc) if we can directly send notifications from firebase console ?
If No then why and what is the best way to use this service?

I really need logical explanation.

please answer me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"if we can directly send notifications from firebase console"

You can't directly send the notification. It will have first go through APNS.

APNS is there to:

- Avoid spamming. If you're sending it every 3 seconds, APNS will restrict you.
- Help preserve battery. This becomes more important for silent notifications. Imagine an app sending a silent notification every 30 seconds. This would affect the battery—without the user knowing about it. He's like I'm not opening any apps, yet my battery is dying faster than normal. This would allow Apple to batch notifications from different apps. Imagine if you had 20 apps each trying to send their silent notification at a specific time, so you would be on for 20 different moments. Now imagine if your device told APNS: "Hey there, I have good battery and a good connection, send me what you got!"